# How can I be sure that a row, or series of rows returned in one select statement are excluded from other queries to the database in separate threads

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 9.2.2 database that serves orders to my ERP system. The database tables contain boolean columns indicating if a customer is added or not among other records. The code I use extracts the rows from the database and sends them to our ERP system one at a time (single threaded). My code works perfectly in this regard; however over the past year our volume has grown enough to require a multi-threaded solution.

I don't think the MVCC modes will work for me because the added_customer column is only updated once a customer has been successfully added. The default MVCC modes could cause the same row to be worked on at the same time resulting in duplicate web service calls. What I want to avoid is duplicate web service calls to our ERP system as they can be rather heavy, although admittedly I am not an expert on MVCC nor the other modes that PostgreSQL provides.

My question is: **How can I be sure that a row, or series of rows returned in one select statement are excluded from other queries to the database in separate threads?**

Comment: Did you consider sending a set of rows rather than one row at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to record the fact that the rows are being processed somehow. You will also need to deal with concurrent attempts to mark them as being processed and handle failures with sending them to your ERP system.

You may find [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) useful to get a set of rows and simultaneously lock them against updates. One approach might be for each thread to select a target row, try to add it's ID to a "processing" table, then remove it in the same transaction you update added_customer.

If a thread fetches no candidate rows, or fails to insert then it just needs to sleep briefly and try again. If anything goes badly wrong then you should have rows left in the "processing" table that you can inspect/correct.

Of course the other option is to just grab a set of candidate rows and spawn a separate process/thread for each that communicates with the ERP. That keeps the database fetching single-threaded while allowing multiple channels to the ERP.

Comment: I will have to check out select for update and see if that will be a viable solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column `user_is_proccesed` to the table. It can hold the process id for the back end, that updates the record.

Then use a small serializable transaction to set the `user_is_proccesed` to "lock row for proccesing".

Something like:

```
START TRANSACTION  ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

UPDATE user_table
SET user_is_proccesed = pg_backend_pid()
WHERE <some condition>
  AND user_is_proccesed IS NULL; -- no one is proccesing it now

COMMIT;
```

The key thing here - with `SERIALIZABLE` only one transaction can successfully update the record (all other concurrent `SERIALIZABLE` updates will fail with `ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update`).